# if let ISO8601DateFormatter from String

Tags: swift3, swift4

I have a response that returns the date of an object and Sometimes it returns the year and sometimes returns the date with the ISO8601DateFormatter style (1995-01-01T00:00:00Z)

The question is how can i get a if let that can identify when the value is a year as String or a ISO8601Date from a string.

Comment: Convert the date string with `DateFormatter` and ISO format or even `ISO8601DateFormatter`. If it fails, it's a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
      let pulledDate = "1995-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withYear, .withMonth, .withDay, .withTime, .withDashSeparatorInDate, .withColonSeparatorInTime]

      if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: pulledDate ?? ""){
          let units: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year]
          let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents(units, from: date)
          print("It is a date year = \(comps.year)")
      }
      else{
          print("It is not a date")
      }
```